GDKmmap fails, try to free up space
LOGS
database 'im_monet' has crashed after start on 2024-04-22 08:02:20, attempting restart, up min/avg/max: 0s/4h/4d, crash average: 1.00 1.00 1.00 (15987-2099=13888)
#GDKmmap(327680) fails, try to free up space [memory in use=20104789296,virtual memory in use=996655480112]
#GDKmalloc(2690064384) fails, try to free up space [memory in use=394318426664,virtual memory in use=1334861410856]
oot@im-monetdb01-ng1:~|⇒  free -h
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           503G         60G        3.6G        4.0G        438G        436G
Swap:           14G          0B         14G
